# Flush/Clear System.in (stdin) before reading

Tags: java, linux, stdin, keyboard-events

At work, we have 5 RFID readers attached to a PC running Linux. The readers are all recognized as keyboards and send their input (what they read form the Chip) as an key-input-event sequence. To be able to tell which reader send what sequence, I'm doing a raw-read over `/dev/input/XX` and get their input this way.

The problem with this is, that the send keyboard-events generated by the RFID readers are still "in" stdin and when I try to read from `System.in` via `Scanner` (input should be generated by a normal keyboard this time), I first get the "pending" input from the readers (which consists of 10 Hex-decimal digits and a newline (`\n`)).

Now, the question is: **How can I flush all these "pending" input's from stdin** and then read what I really want from the keyboard?

I tried:

```
System.in.skip(System.in.available());
```

But seek is not allowed on stdin (`skip` throws an `IOException`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < System.in.available(); i++){
  System.in.read();
}
```

But `available()` doesn't estimate enough (still stuff in stdin afterwards).

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
  scanner.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Clean!");
```

But `hasNextLine()` never becomes `false` (the print never executes).

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);
System.out.println("Clean!");
```

Same as above.

Anyone with any more ideas?

Comment: [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) may block if there is no input, so I suspect your print statement never executes for that reason. Not a solution, but an observation of why at least one of your approaches has failed.

Comment: (not enough rep to comment)... This is awesome: This worked for me **System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()])** user5466753**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on **@Joni**'s advice, i put this together:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
        scanner.next(); // Just discard this, not interested...
    }
}
```

This discards the data that is already "pending" in stdin and waits until valid data is entered. Valid, in this context, meaning a decimal integer.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()])
```

Answer (score 2):

A related one.

I read a double, then needed to read a string.

Below worked correctly:

```
double d = scanner.nextDouble();
scanner.nextLine(); // consumes \n after the above number(int,double,etc.)
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in portable way to flush the data in an input stream. If you know that the pending data ends with `\n` why don't you read until you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Devices usually send data using a well defined protocol which you can use to parse data segments.

If I'm right, discard data that isn't properly formatted for the protocol. This allows you to filter out the data you aren't interested in.

As I'm not familiar with the RFID scanner you're using I can't be of more help, but this is what I suggest.

Comment: The incoming data is probably formatted and I'm also interested in it, but not at that later time. I suspect that the data is still in stdio because I never took it from stdio, but read it from the device itself instead...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with multiple threads.

1. Your real application reads from a PipedInputStream that is connected to a PipedOutputStream
2. You need to have one thread reading from `System.in` continuously. As long as the real application is not interested in the data coming from System.in (indicated by a boolean flag), this thread discards everything that it reads. But when the real application sets the flag to indicate that it is interested in the data coming from System.in, then this thread sends all the data that it reads to the PipedOutputStream.
3. Your real application turns on the flag to indicate that it is interested in the data, and clears the flag when it is no longer interested in the data.

This way, the data from `System.in` is always automatically flushed/clead

Answer (score 0):

The best practice (that I've found) when dealing with ***terminals*** (aka. the console) is to ***deal with i/o a line at a time***.  So the ideal thing to do is ***get the entire line of user input, as a string***, and then ***parse it as you see fit***.  Anything else is not only implementation specific, but also prone to blocking.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = "";

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter something...");

    try {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        //Parse `line` string as you see fit here...
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

I include the `while` & `try/catch` blocks so that the prompt will loop infinitely on invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```java
System.in.skipNBytes(System.in.available());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).