# Multi-word scanner input in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, user-input, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to use if-else statement dependant upon the user's input. It works when the user's input is only one word, however, multiple word inputs go unrecognized and triggers the else statement. How can i resolve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MyFirstJavaClass {

`public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    System.out.println("Catch the tiger or run away?");
    answer = myScanner.next();


         if (answer.equals("Catch the tiger"  )) {
            System.out.println("You've been mauled by a tiger! What were you thinking?");
            answer = myScanner.next();          

    } else {
        System.out.println("run away");
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
answer = myScanner.next();
```

With:

```
answer = myScanner.nextLine();
```

next will only read in the next value until it reaches a space or newline. You want to read in the full line before making the comparison

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
        scanner.next(); // Just discard this, not interested...
    }
}
```

Reference :
[Flush/Clear System.in (stdin) before reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273751/flush-clear-system-in-stdin-before-reading)

Comment: how comes hasNextInt() here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstJavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Catch the tiger or run away?");
        if (myScanner.hasNext("Catch the tiger")) {
            System.out.println("You've been mauled by a tiger! What were you thinking?");
        } else {
            System.out.println("run away");
        }
    }
}
```