# Split function issue?

Tags: java, string, split, tokenize

> removeplayer user1

Code works fine with above input on console. It successfully removes player 'user1' for me. However, if user does not mention any username, then it prompts to removes all the players present in the array-list.

> removeplayer(followed by enter), below code fails as str[1] is nothing over here. 
>   But I want str[1] as if this value is null, it helps me to remove all the players.

```
param="0";

System.out.print(">");

//type_op= in.next();

String str=in.nextLine();

String[] str1=str.split(" ");

type_op = str1[0];

param = str1[1];

String[] param_split = param.split(",");

if(type_op.equals("removeplayer") && param.equals(null))

removeAllPlayers();

else if(type_op.equals("removeplayer"))

removeplayer();
```

I have tried using next() as well, but in that case the problem gets more complicated as in that case only removeAllPlayers() works.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is... Does the error occur when the user writes `removeplayer` only in the console? If so, you have to check whether `str1.length` is 1. If it is, then assign `param=null`. If it isn't, then assign `param = str1[1]`.

Comment: yes this works now by checking the length of str1 as 1. Cheers!!

Comment: I got this working. However, this bit of code[System.out.print(">");String str = in.nextLine();] runs one extra time once any of the operation is completed.  This is happening for 3 of my operations. I debugged and checked what is the problem, however I have no clue what is wrong. The funny part is that the above 2 lines run one extra time for some of the operations. Compiler goes to in.nextLine(), does not ask me to give input, and then re-runs in the next iteration where it asks for the input. One of the iteration is happening without inputting any value.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to check immediately the str1 array in order to know if there is no user specified, by checking the array length:

```
param = "0";

System.out.print(">");

//type_op= in.next();
String str = in.nextLine();

String[] str1 = str.split(" ");

type_op = str1[0];

if (type_op.equals("removeplayer") && str1.length == 1) {
    removeAllPlayers();
} else if (type_op.equals("removeplayer")) {

    param = str1[1];

    String[] param_split = param.split(",");

    removeplayer();
}
```

This is just a simple and quick solution, but it should work.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: I got this working. However, this bit of code[System.out.print(">");String str = in.nextLine();] runs one extra time once any of the operation is completed. This is happening for 3 of my operations. I debugged and checked what is the problem, however I have no clue what is wrong. The funny part is that the above 2 lines run one extra time for some of the operations. Compiler goes to in.nextLine(), does not ask me to give input, and then re-runs in the next iteration where it asks for the input. One of the iteration is happening without inputting any value.

Comment: You problem is not really clear. So, I suppose your 'in' object is a Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); right? Therefore probably there is already some carriage return in the standard in buffer before you read in.nextLine(), maybe due to some previous interaction with the user. If this is the case you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273751/flush-clear-system-in-stdin-before-reading

Answer (score 0):

Just compare it as

if(type_op.equals("removeplayer") && **param==null**)

removeAllPlayers();

Comment: this will not work as array goes out of bound. str[1] does not exist. I have implemented this by checking the size of str1.